# Release application does't work in android 5 and 5.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

i have an application that does't work in android 5 and 5.1 (API 21 and 22) but work fine in other android version (6,7 and 8) and i get a weird bug in my google play console. i use `multidex` because i have a lot of library in the application but i don't think the problem for it ' any help !

> ```
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: 
> >       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5558)
> >       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:5150)
> >       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5090)
> >       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600 (ActivityThread.java:177)
> >       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1509)
> >       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
> >       at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
> >       at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5938)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
> >       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> ```
>
> (ZygoteInit.java:1400)
>
> > ```
> >   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1195)
> > Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
> >   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
> >   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
> >   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
> >   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5543)
> > ```

And this my `build.gradle`

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 7
        versionName "2.01"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        //for export the the room database scheme
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.support}"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:${versions.constraint}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.support}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${versions.support}"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${versions.glide}"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:${versions.glide}"

    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${versions.butterKnife}"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${versions.butterKnife}"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${versions.retrofit}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${versions.retrofit}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${versions.rxjava2_adapter}"

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:${versions.arch}"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:${versions.arch}"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:${versions.arch}"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:${versions.arch}"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${versions.arch}"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${versions.rxAndroid}"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${versions.rxJava}"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:${versions.rxBinding}"

    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${versions.timber}"

    implementation "com.ahmedabdelmeged:networkito:${versions.networkito}"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${versions.dagger}"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${versions.dagger}"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${versions.dagger}"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${versions.dagger}"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${versions.dagger}"

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${versions.okhttp3}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${versions.okhttp3}"

    implementation "com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:${versions.image_shape}"

    implementation "joda-time:joda-time:${versions.joda}"

    implementation "org.greenrobot:eventbus:${versions.eventbus}"

    implementation "com.google.android:flexbox:${versions.flexbox}"

    implementation "com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:${versions.photoView}"

    implementation "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:${versions.circleImageView}"

    implementation "com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:${versions.ViewPagerIndicator}"

    implementation("io.branch.sdk.android:library:${versions.branch}") {
        exclude module: 'answers-shim'
    }

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${versions.firebase}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:${versions.firebase}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:${versions.firebase}"

    implementation "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh:${versions.pushwoosh}"
    implementation "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-badge:${versions.pushwoosh}"

    implementation "com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:${versions.twitter}"

    implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${versions.crashlytics}") {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:${versions.answers}") {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation "com.vimeo.stag:stag-library:${versions.stag}"
    annotationProcessor "com.vimeo.stag:stag-library-compiler:${versions.stag}"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation("com.mopub:mopub-sdk:${versions.mopub}") {
        transitive = true
        exclude module: 'libAvid-mopub' // To exclude AVID
        exclude module: 'moat-mobile-app-kit' // To exclude Moat
    }

    implementation "com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:${versions.facebook}"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${versions.play_service}"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Do you have `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` under `dependencies`; , in your `Manifest` file: `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication`;  and `MultiDex.install(this);` in `MyApplication` activity?

Comment: actually i don't need this the docs say you need this if i use api below 21 . and i already do it and give me the same problem

Comment: Have your Application override `attachBaseContext` ?

Comment: yes the same but i don't need this my min sdk is 21

Comment: You need to add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` under `dependencies`.

Comment: i add already all of this before but does't work

Comment: Check this blog: https://androidhumanrobot.blogspot.rs/2015/05/multidex-issue-in-android-development.html

Comment: As @Stanojkovic reminded you have to add multidex into your dependency.

Comment: actually not i fix my problem without adding them

Comment: @Ahmed Abd-Elmeged, how did you solve your problem?

Comment: i will put the solution in the answer

Answer (score 0):

After long search i found a solution for my problem but i don't understand it. but i work for me if any one explain it. i will be good

i add the following to my `build.gradle`

in the android config

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

And in the `build.gradle` it self

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
```